# Android. Можно ли динамически поменять название Модели данных

Tags: java, android

В андроид студио можно динамически поменять название класса

```
Class cls = Class.forName("net.artsait.bukv.MyClass");
```

Есть ли что-нибудь пододмное, что бы поменять динамически названия модели данных

Например есть

```
Contact contact;
```

И вместо `Contact` подставлялось другое значение взависимости от ситуации

Comment: А разве то, что Вы написали в первой части сообщения, и то, что во второй – это не одно и то же?

Comment: Я сократил. В первой я написал про Класс, но позже понял, что это не то что нужно. Может кому-то пригодиться поэтому удалять не стал.

Comment: Объявите просто `Object contact`, и сможете записать в него что угодно

Comment: ??? можно немного подробней. У меня есть значения в String ss = "r"; 
Можно ли вместо Contact contact; записать r contact?

Comment: У вас есть значение, которое вы туда хотите записать?

Comment: Содержимое String ss; динамически меняется, я хочу чтобы то что находиться в String ss подставлялось вместо Contact

Comment: зачем это вам нужно? что вы потом хотите сделать с этим полем?

Comment: Как я уже написал пример с Классом
Class cls = Class.forName("net.artsait.bukv."+ss);

Что-то вроде этого но не с класом , а с моделью данных

Comment: Если отвечаете мне, то пишите @metalurgus. Так мне будет приходить уведомление. Без ссылки вы просто комментируете свой вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46243/discussion-between-metalurgus-and-artsait).